# How to calculate grid width?

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I would like to create a simple JS script that will loop through all columns in my layout and calculate if one of the columns could be two columns wide.

So my standard layout is three columns and I will than calculate if one of the three columns in a row can be two columns wide. If it is the first or second one in a row it should add a class to the first or second column that makes the column two columns width.

I came up with the following, but now I am stuck at it:

```
// Grid calculation
    function gridCalc() {
        // Variables
        var container;
        var row;
        var item;

        container = document.getElementsByClassName('overview');

        container.row = document.getElementsByClassName('uniWrapper')[2];
        container.row.item = document.getElementsByClassName('infoItem');
        console.log(container.row.item);

        for (var i = container.row.item.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {

        };

        // Get elements and store them in a var
        // Check the width of its container
        // If first or second in a row add class '2columns' random two one of the two

    } gridCalc();
```

I don't know how to start this script.

Comment: If you want to start this function immediately, you can make use of self invoking function `(function gridCalc() { // Code } )();` Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a nice next step, but know that was not what I am trying to do. I would like to add random a 2columns width to an element, by calculate if it fits in a row to create a 2columns column. @ManojKumar